# Optimizing multiple continuous animations that are heating up device

Tags: ios, swift, animation, optimization, uiview

I’m working on a project that has about 16 `UIViews` on a `ViewController`.

Some of the `UIView` contain some processor intensive `CG` drawings with transparency done at load time, while other `UIView` are animating. In particular, the following rotating animations run continuously. (If I look very closely, the animations appear not entirely smooth.)

The device I’m testing on is warming up, it’s not hot, but getting very warm. I’m concerned I’m overloading the processor.

**Question:**

Is there a more efficient way to complete the below animations which run continuously using a method that is less resource hungry and prevents the device from heating up?

**Xcode instruments:**

*At load (max):* **CPU**: 56% - **Memory**: 29MB

*When running (max):* **CPU**: 1% - **Memory**: 29MB

```
    func rotateForward() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.viewA.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.viewA.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            self.viewB.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.viewB.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            self.viewC.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.viewC.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            self.viewD.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.viewD.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            self.rotateForward()
        }
    }

    func rotateBack() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.viewW.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.viewW.transform, -CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            self.viewX.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.viewX.transform, -CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            self.viewY.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.viewY.transform, -CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            self.viewZ.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.viewZ.transform, -CGFloat(M_PI_2))
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            self.rotateBack()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using CPU to run these animation , you can use GPU to perform them.
You can use this protocol to make the view rotate forward. Try to subclass the views to implement this protocol and try it out.

```
protocol Rotate{ }

extension Rotate where Self: UIView {

    func rotate() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        animation.duration = 2
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        animation.fromValue =  0.0
        animation.toValue = Float(M_PI * 2.0)
        layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to rotate it.

Comment: Is it using less CPU now? Layer animations use the GPU directly to perform animations , unlike View animations that use CPU directly.